# Reading from file with lines of varying number of tokens

Tags: java, file, input, token

This is the data in myFile.txt, the first line has 4 tokens, the second has 3, and the last has 4 tokens. The last token, an int, indicates the persons salary. If no salary, the no integer, and thus one less token.

```
Peter, 22, m, 1200
Nina, 24, f
Oscar, 40,m, 40000
```

Obviously the while loop further down, would give me an inputMisMatchException, so is there a good way for reading textfiles where each line my have one extra/less token?

```
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
     String name = input.next();
     int age = input.nextInt();
     String gender = input.next();
     int salary = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can add `hasNextInt` to check if the next token is integer or not:

```
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
     String name = input.next();
     int age = input.nextInt();
     String gender = input.next();
     if (input.hasNextInt()) {
         int salary = input.nextInt();
         ...
     }
}
```

However, this is not universal: what if the first column of the file is also an `int`?

A better approach would be to read your input line-by-line, split on commas and spaces, and then parse the data based on the number of available tokens:

```
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = input.nextLine();
     String[] tokens = input.split(" ,");
     String name = tokens[0];
     int age = Integer.valueOf(tokens[1]);
     String gender = tokens[2];
     if (tokens.length > 3) {
         int salary = Integer.valueOf(tokens[3]);
         ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You could read the entire line using `String line = input.nextLine();` and then use `line.split(", ");` to split the tokens and store them in an array.
- Then you can iterate through the array and get the values as `array[0]` is name and `array[1]` is age and so on...